# How to bind a function to "Click" event of a dynamically added ImageButton?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-controls

I am completely new to Asp.net.

I am currently working on a asp.net page coded via Visual Basic

On the page I have these image buttons that are dynamically generated based on the SQL Data the page retrieves.

Unfortunately I could not figure out how to bind a click function to each of these buttons.

the [Control Name].onClick = "Function Name()" is for clientSide scripts.

and I need to bind

```
Protected Sub Button_InsertNewTextBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_InsertNewTextBox.Click
```

to the dynamically allocated buttons.

I couldn't figure out how.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I believe in Visual Basic the [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka(VS.80).aspx) statement is what you're after

Comment: I tried using AddHandler
     "AddHandler currentButton.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_InsertNewTextBox_Click"     

But the function was never called.

Is it some unique property of ASP web page that prevents it from working?

Comment: you may need to put it in the page_load method or something like that